# Image style height and width not taken in outlook mails

Tags: html, css, outlook, windows-live-mail

I have a following dom structure in html content I am sending as email.

```
<a href="http://content.mindmatrix.net/email/814xjqjmpj5r/b59tqx7tzz2x7"
 target="_new">
<span style='text-decoration:none;text-underline:none'>
<img border=0 id="_x0000_i1026"
 src="http://dev.mindmatrix.net/page/e7c9cf53-bae8-4024-a561-355f950cb26b/635246986810000000/original.jpeg?userid=cozmwz91irkm1"
 style='border-bottom-color:black;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:
 1px;border-left-color:black;border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:1px;
 border-right-color:black;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:1px;
 border-top-color:black;border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:1px;
 height:150px;width:120px'>
</span></a>
```

I am giving style `height:150px;width:120px` to image for making it of size thumbnail. Actual height and width of this image is very large. Problem is, this style is not taken when mail goes in outlook inbox. So my questions are -

1)How can i make the css work for setting height and width.

2) Image appears blur in **Windown live mail**. I am not sure whether it will persist in outlook when i will succeed in fixing style of height and width. so how can i fix this

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Put the width and height in separate attributes, with no unit:

```
<img style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;"
src="images/img.jpg" width="120" height="150">
```

Another Option:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<style type="text/css">
img.header { width: 600px; } /* or something like that */
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Don't include "px" in width or height img attributes - they're only used in CSS.

Comment: @CalvT: yup. using without pixels fixed the problem.

Comment: You should remove the first "temptative answer" to avoid confussion. HTML attributes don't have units.

Comment: I have same problem for image which is not showing correctly in outlook.and I am using px and % for applying height and width for image. but when i removed px and % and using only just whatever the value in html it is worked for me.
For example i was using : width="800px" now I'm using widht="800" and problem is resolved for me.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work with zero height and width.

Comment: Removing the "px" worked for me. You can still use "%" though like this `width='10%' height='10%'`

Comment: It should be sufficient to just set width; height will be adjusted automatically.

Comment: It is indeed a flaw of Outlook that it doesn't parse the 'style' tag properly.

Comment: @BlueSix - thanks! it was the px. I removed it and everything fell into place beautifully! (I guess we can't fault Outlook for its adherence to the HTML standard.)

Answer (score 26):

The px needs to be left off, for some odd reason.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted so much, fixed image sizing issues on Outlook 2010 for me...

Comment: Could you elaborate on this answer please? This could affect non-outlook readers negatively?

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me:

```
src="{0}"  width=30 height=30 style="border:0;"
```

Nothing else has worked so far.

Answer (score 15):

Can confirm that leaving px out from width and height did the trick for Outlook

```
<img src="image.png" style="height: 55px;width:139px;border:0;" height="55" width="139">
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the pleasure of creating an email for Outlook 2010 based on Sharepoint data. But when creating an Outlook email, Outlook in its wisdom reduces the image width and height to cm. Interestingly using the width and height kicks in correctly when you forward the email but not when you open it.

**Hack Fix:**

I had an image [720px X 150px] which should be [19.05cm X 3.98cm] BUT Outlook set the image width and height to [15.24cm X 3.18cm]. ***Clearly this is a problem***.

The hack I used was setting the HTML image tag as follows:

```
<img src="...." style="width:720px; height:150px" width="900" height="187.5" />
```

Why that width and height?

Well it is the ratio (25% increase)
between

- *what Outlook was saying* and
- *what it should be* by adding 25% of the current size; which is `(720 X 1.25 = 900)` and `(150 X 1.25 = 187.5)`.

It's not pretty but it works.

Answer (score 6):

```html
<img id="_x0000_i1026" src="images/img.jpg" width="120" height="150" />
```

This worked for me both in gmail and outlook.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me in Outlook:

`<img src="image.jpg" width="120" style="display:block;width:100%" />`

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem for image which is not showing correctly in outlook.and I am using px and % for applying height and width for image. but when i removed px and % and using only just whatever the value in html it is worked for me. For example i was using : width="800px" now I'm using widht="800" and problem is resolved for me.

Answer (score 0):

make the image the exact size needed in the email. Windows MSO has a hard time resizing images in different scenarios.

in the case of using a 1px by 1px transparent png or gif as a spacer, defining the dimensions via width, height, or style attributes will work as expected in the majority of clients, but not windows MSO (of course).

example use case - you are using a background image and need to position a  with a link inside over some part of the background image. Using a 1px by 1px spacer gif/png will only expand so wide (about 30px). You need size the spacer to the exact dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe caused by the mail client's stylesheet.

**For example**, the foxmail mail client will add the following styles:

```css
.mail_content * > img:not([norescale]) {
    max-width: 100%;
    height:auto !important
}
```

So any image without the `norescale` attribute will have height auto style.

The solution is add `norescale="norescale"` to the img tag.

Answer (score 0):

This solution work for me. Pay attention to attributes that doesnt have PX at the end. Also empty spaces: