# Outlook ignores image height and only shows small part of image

Tags: html, css, outlook, newsletter

I'm sending out HTML newsletter campaigns for customers but Outlook will only show small parts of the images in it. I've already read the [existing article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989897/image-style-height-and-width-not-taken-in-outlook-mails) on this but there is no solution to the problem there.

Oldschool HTML and some inline CSS that is recommended by Mailchimp/Campaignmonitor to make HTML newsletters work in Outlook:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="mainTable" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;border: 0;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="text-align:left;background-color:#ccdce3;width:600px;"><img src="gematik_header.jpg" style="width:600px;height:339px;" width="600" height="339" alt="Frohe Weihnachten"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="text-align:left; background-color:#ccdce3;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;line-height:24px;margin:0;padding:0;color:#646464;">
      <div style="margin: 0 135px 0 175px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px; height:100%; padding:0; color: #646464;">
        <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px; margin:0; padding:0; color: #646464;">Text</p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="text-align:center; background-color:#ccdce3;height: 380px;" height="380"><img src="gematik_footer.jpg" alt="gematik" style="width:100%; height:auto;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried to double-define the width and height with HTML attribute and CSS but always the same: looking good in browsers, Apple Mail, Thunderbird, gmail, Lotus Notes and even Outlook 2000 to 2003 but not in Outlook 2007 and later. Small parts of the images are there but I can't make the size they should be. See the screenshots:

[image: See the screenshot]

Comment: That's odd, `<img src="gematik_header.jpg" width="600" height="339" alt="Frohe Weihnachten">` should work just fine in the Outlook's. Almost seems that the image files aren't loading. Are the screenshots above from an actual installation of Outlook? Or a preview software like Litmus or Email On Acid?

Comment: Yes, it's odd. This is a screenshot my customer sent to me from his Outlook. I also checked on Litmus to see if it is my customers installation that's causing the error but Litmus gave the same result. The only solution I could offer my customer in this case was to put the whole thing into one image. It's working but no solution to the problem.